# Computational complexity of a CNN network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, deep-neural-networks, fully-convolutional-networks

In the following network, the convolution operations of convolutional blocks are performed by three 1-D kernels with the sizes 8, 5, and 3 respectively along with stride equal to 1. The final network is constructed by stacking three convolution blocks with the filters of sizes 128, 256, and 128 in each block. Pooling operation is excluded from the network. I wanted to find the computational complexity of the following network. I was wondering if you could give me some hints to compute the computational complexity of this network. I appreciate your time! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: By "computational complexity", do you mean the time complexity of the forward pass?

Comment: @nbro I am curious to know how expensive this network is! Is it possible to know the overall complexity of this network? It would be nice to know the time complexity of the overall network as well.

Comment: There's a very similar question here: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/22913/2444, to which I gave an answer where I give some hints. Let me know if your question is a duplicate of that one.