# Is there a literature on the time complexity of Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, academia, computational-complexity

There exist various blog posts describing the **time complexity** of Fully Connected Neural Networks [(1](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/5728/what-is-the-time-complexity-for-training-a-neural-network-using-back-propagation/20281), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53843459/neural-networks-and-big-o), [3](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-determine-the-computational-time-complexity-Big-O-of-back-propagation-in-a-feedforward-neural-network), [4)](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/13612/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-the-forward-pass-algorithm-of-a-feedforward-neura); Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) [(5)](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/22913/what-is-the-computational-complexity-of-the-forward-pass-of-a-convolutional-neur) and of Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM) networks [(6)](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/33927/what-is-the-time-complexity-for-testing-a-stacked-lstm-model). However, this question seems to be absent in the **academic literature** or at least I couldn't find it. Furthermore, papers that go towards this question seem to consider mostly experimental results [(7](https://doi.org/10.1109/MACISE49704.2020.00039), [8)](https://doi.org/10.1109/BigData.2018.8622396).

Therefore, my question is:

- Is there a literature on the time complexity of Neural Networks that gives **analytic expressions** in the fashion of [$\mathcal O(\cdot)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)?
- If this is not the case this is because...

  - ...(1-6) is **common sense**?
  - ...it is **not that easy to answer** and the blog posts only present a simplified form of the problem?
  - ...something different?

Although I consider the posts mentioned above very useful, there are various reasons why one would prefer to cite a paper rather than a website [(10)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/161984)!

Comment: We have other posts other than the only one from our AISE site that you're linking to. See [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/13612/2444), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/33927/2444), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/23998/2444), [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/22913/2444), etc., some of them answered by myself. So, I recommend that you go through all these posts and update yours with links to them, and revise your question, if necessary.